# set page refresh after interval

Tags: wordpress, page-refresh

I am Using the following code to refresh the webpage at particular interval. The page seems to refresh but the stats are not showing up in google analytics. Would be great if you guys could help me out.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh_handler() {
    function refresh() {
       var url = $(location).attr('href');
       window.history.pushState("", "<?php echo $meta_title; ?>", url);
       $("#ajaxanalytics").load("http://www.website.com/wp-content/themes/themename/inc-analytics.php"); 
    }
    setInterval(refresh, 60*1000); //every 1 minutes
}
$(document).ready(refresh_handler);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code on `inc-analytics.php` sends the data to Google Analytics?

You need to trigger the Google Analytics send pageview before reloading the page if it's not in the content of the `inc-analytics.php` code.

Comment: The code on inc-analytics.php is the tracking info that is provided by Google Analytics

Comment: `<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>`




This is the code being used in teh inc-analytics.php

Comment: Fix that code between the `<head>` tag and make this:

`setInterval(function(){
        ga('send', 'pageview', {page: new_url});
}, 500);`